# How do I get Filename without extension?

Tags: php, filenames

I have a site I am working on with over 11000 product pages. They are written is .php

I am trying to add the file name (without the file extension .php) to the file for identifying the current page.

Example:
If the file name is

```
product1.php
```

A line of code

```
$thisPage = "product1"
```

Will be added to each page withing the top PHP tag. I have tried to find a solution to this for longer than I care to admit, and while I am a PHP newb, it seems like their must be a simple solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

```
$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

Is what I know to use to get the name of the file. I can the truncate $currentPage to remove the ".php" from the string. I will then be left with the text I want to write to the file.

The difficulty I am having, is writing it to the file, not echoing the name but actually writing the file name as a new string for later use.

So what I will be left with

```
$currentPage = "the-truncated-file-name-text"
```

Unique to each page for use indexing

So something like "write($currentPage)" to the file

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
$filename = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$thisPage = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

You'll want to stay away from magic constants like `__FILE__` as they will return the *current running file*, i.e., if the code is in an include file, the path of the included file will be returned, not the script requested by the visitor.

Answer (score 2):

[php.net](http://php.net) is a wonderful resource.

The  [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function is what you want.  It splits a path or filename into its constituent parts.

Alternatively you could explode on '.'

```
list($file, $ext) = explode('.',$myfile);
```

to write it to your file then call

```
file_put_contents($filename, $stringtoadd, FILE_APPEND);
```

however note that doing this will make your file no longer a valid CSV file as the format of the last line will not be correct.

Comment: But how do I write that as a hardcoded string into the current file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get a list of the files in a directory. Then use [substr](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the last 4 characters from the file name.